# CircleCI FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, continuous-integration, circleci, fastlane

I am building an app on CircleCI. I have tried `xcodebuild` and `fastlane scan`. After dependencies successfully install, the follow build error occurs.

```
Testing failed:
    Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/distiller/project/node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm'

** TEST FAILED **
[17:53:06]: Exit status: 65

[!] Error building the application. See the log above.
```

However, if I run the test command locally or SSH into CircleCI, then the build succeeds. What is the problem?